# How to hide classes with PHP/Javascript if/else conditional at wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, user-interface, notifications

I have some problems with conditional (if/else) at Wordpress function.
I need to hide this `<span class="xs-item-count highlight xscart"><?php echo esc_html($xs_product_count); ?></span>` if the value `$xs_product_count` is 0 on a cart.
What should I do?

I've tried using PHP Native, but My Website has an error.

My belonging code is:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" class ="mobile-cart-notif offset-cart-menu">
   <span class="xs-item-count highlight xscart">
      <?php echo esc_html($xs_product_count); ?>
   </span>
   <i class="icon icon-bag"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: *"I've tried using PHP Native, but My Website has an error."* ... could you show us what you tried so we don't end up posting what you've already done; e.g. wrapping it in an `if` statement: `<?php if($xs_product_count): ?> ... <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: I try on a child theme function. Maybe, because I am a newbie on WordPress and worried if I change the original theme functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" class="mobile-cart-notif offset-cart-menu">
    <?php if ((int) $xs_product_count > 0) : ?>
        <span class="xs-item-count highlight xscart">
            <?php echo esc_html($xs_product_count); ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
   <i class="icon icon-bag"></i>
</a>
```

Putting the `(int)` in front of the `$xs_product_count` in the `if` statement is called "[casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)" a variable to a type, and it'll change the string of `'0'` to integer `0` which lets us reliably compare with the `>` operator.

Comment: Since PHP is loosely typed you could just do: `<?php if($xs_product_count): ?>` (i.e. just check that it's *truthy*)

Comment: Sure. But trying to encourage the writing of code that's also easily parseable by *humans*. :)

Comment: Hey, you've used the alternative `if ... endif` syntax here - that already makes it 10x more parseable (for humans) in my book ;)

Comment: Every little counts!

Comment: It works!. But it showed only when users refresh their browser :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" class ="mobile-cart-notif offset-cart-menu">
<?php if (0 < $xs_product_count) {?>
   <span class="xs-item-count highlight xscart">
      <?php echo esc_html($xs_product_count); ?>
   </span>
<?php } ?>
   <i class="icon icon-bag"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below condition before span tag.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" class ="mobile-cart-notif offset-cart-menu">
<?php     
if($xs_product_count != 0 ){
?>
   <span class="xs-item-count highlight xscart">
      <?php echo esc_html($xs_product_count); ?>
   </span>
<?php } ?>
   <i class="icon icon-bag"></i>
</a>
```

Or you can hide complete section by below code.

```
<?php     
if($xs_product_count != 0 ){
?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" class ="mobile-cart-notif offset-cart-menu">

   <span class="xs-item-count highlight xscart">
      <?php echo esc_html($xs_product_count); ?>
   </span>
   <i class="icon icon-bag"></i>
</a>
<?php } ?>
```